# Is there any kind of authoritative guide to Apple's Volume Purchase Program, Device Enrollment Program, and Mobile Device Management?

Tags: automated-device-enrollment, volume-purchase-program

I'm fairly new to the whole world of Apple and macOS. As I'm currently writing my thesis about the possible enrollment of macOS devices via [Device Enrollment Program](https://www.apple.com/business/docs/site/DEP_Guide.pdf) (DEP) (in connecting with some other stuff), I searched the Web, books and the Apple's Developer documentation, but I have not found a reliable guide on how to use [Volume Purchase Program](https://volume.itunes.apple.com/?l=en) (VPP) and DEP (or at least a "quotable" description), only the handbook for ABM (which is pretty good, but does not answer all my questions).

Am I just blind or are there some "hidden" gems that i seem to overlook? Maybe there is a guide in [Apple Business Manager](https://business.apple.com) (ABM) directly, to which i don't have access - yet - ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure if you'd searched the Web just with the keywords that you have listed, you'd get a lot of official resources right on the first page of the search results.

But nonetheless, here are some links to get you started:

1. [Apple Deployment Programs - Volume Purchase Program Guide](https://www.apple.com/business/docs/site/VPP_Business_Guide.pdf)
2. [Apple Deployment Programs - Device Enrollment Program Guide](https://www.apple.com/business/docs/site/DEP_Guide.pdf)
3. [Apple Deployment Reference - Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/deployment-reference-macos/welcome/web)
4. [Apple Deployment Reference - iPhone and iPad](https://support.apple.com/guide/deployment-reference-ios/welcome/web)
5. [Mobile Device Management Settings](https://support.apple.com/guide/mdm/welcome/web)
6. [Apple Deployment Programs](https://deploy.apple.com/)
7. [Upgrade from Apple Deployment Programs](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT209617)
8. [Volume Purchase Program](https://vpp.itunes.apple.com/)
9. [Apple Business Manager User Guide](https://support.apple.com/guide/apple-business-manager/welcome/web)
10. [Business Support](https://support.apple.com/business)
11. [Getting Started Guide - Apple Business Manager](https://www.apple.com/business/docs/site/Apple_Business_Manager_Getting_Started_Guide.pdf)
12. [Upgrade your organization to Apple Business Manager](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208817)